# iam writing this script but it is showing or is unknown opertor

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to search the data and want to satisfy two conditions. For that Iam using an or operator in aggregate function.But it is showing error that 'or' is unknown operator.

This is my code

```
var riderDB = req.body.year_of_birth; 

var riderAge = moment().diff(riderDB, 'years'); 
var search_data = { $match: {"deleted" : {"$ne" : 
1},"provider_status":"Active"}};
if(riderAge != '') 

{ 
   search_data.$match['age'] = { $or: [{'$gte' :  riderAge,'$eq':''}]} 
} 
provider.aggregate([ search_data]);
```

Comment: var riderDB = req.body.year_of_birth;
var riderAge = moment().diff(riderDB, 'years');
if(riderAge != '') {
 search_data.$match['age'] = {'$gte' :  riderAge,'$eq':''} 
}                                               this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Use or condition as below.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          count: {
            "$gte": 15
          }
        },
        {
          count: {
            "$eq": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juNLr.png)

Sample playground on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3qZEd4gNV9H)

Comment: Hi @naveen-reddy welcome to the SO club. Since you used https://mongoplayground.net/ for you answer, it would be kind to share link to your playground and copypaste resulting code. Please, care about readers of your answer.

Comment: I am writing the match condition and assiging to a variable in that i am writing the or condition and assigning to aggregate

Comment: Hi @NaveenReddy welcome to SO! single line answers, and answers that are primarily links are considered to be poor quality, and as such are likely to be flagged for closure.

If you want to have your answer accepted / upvoted, please ensure the code you wrote using the playground is replicated here (as well as with the link) if you'd like, and accompanied by an explanation of what you did to solve the OPs question.